Can't delete Apex class from production, deployment fails with "This Batchable class is in use. : Apex Sharing Recalculation", but no job queued?
I created a batch class to update some records a few days ago, and ran it on the same day. I left the class in production, unused, so I could delete it when I had some time to spare.
When I proceeded to delete the class, I got this error from the CLI:
Component Failures [2]
=============================================================================================================
| Type  Name                        Problem                                                       Line:Column
| ───── ─────────────────────────── ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── ───────────
| Error AccountLastActorUpdateBatch This Batchable class is in use. : Apex Sharing Recalculation.
| Error AccountLastActorUpdateBatch This Batchable class is in use. : Apex Sharing Recalculation.

How can I delete the class then?

When I checked the "apex jobs" page, filtering by status, I couldn't see any jobs pending. However, when I queried them with the Developer Console, some rows were showing as "processing" still.
The query I used was this:
SELECT Id, Status, ApexClass.Name
FROM AsyncApexJob
WHERE ApexClass.Name = 'AccountLastActorUpdateBatch'
AND Status IN ('Queued', 'Processing') 

By iterating this list in the Apex anonymous execution window, and calling System.abortJob, I managed to get rid of these dangling processes. After that, the destrutive changes command worked:
List<AsyncApexJob> jobs = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM AsyncApexJob
    WHERE ApexClass.Name = 'AccountLastActorUpdateBatch'
    AND Status IN ('Queued', 'Processing')
];

for (AsyncApexJob aj : jobs) {
    System.abortJob(aj.Id);
}

sf project deploy start --manifest destructiveChanges/package.xml -l RunSpecifiedTests -t AccountLastActorUpdateBatchTest -w 20 -o prod --pre-destructive-changes destructiveChanges/destructiveChangesPre.xml


Interesting! So this class was not used for processing __share records at all? The only reason it was listed as "...Batchable class is in use...Apex Sharing Recalculation" is that it triggered a re-calculation, and the completion of the job went somehow unnoticed by Salesforce?!

Nope, it didn't touch sharing records directly at all. Plus, this job in particular only changed one picklist on the account record which is completely unrelated to the sharing settings of it!
